# Does Outlook 2007 support named styles?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, styles

A routine email I prepare consists of a narrative section and two evidence sections.  I want the narrative in 11-point Calibri and the evidence in 9-point Bitstream Monospace.

A CSS solution would involve div.classname.

A Word solution would involve a named style (I think).

With Outlook 2007, my practice has been to paste the data, then apply the font changes, every single time.

Is the problem that Outlook is for time management, so workflow automation and typeset-quality documents are Not a Development Priority, or am I missing something?

A search for *named styles* in the Outlook documentation summons up a document which contains the words named and styles, but nothing that answers the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outlook 2007 has *Quick Styles*.  They are visible within the New Message dialog on the *Format Text* tab:

[image]

I was able to add a new style:

1. Formatted some existing text
2. Highlighting it
3. Clicking "Quick Styles"
4. Clicking "Save Selection as a New Quick Style"

Answer (score 0):

Outlook 2007 supports [using Word as it's e-mail editor/composer](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/turn-word-on-or-off-as-your-e-mail-editor-or-viewer-HP005242849.aspx).  If you choose this option, you can use the named styles built into work.  If you do not choose this option, I'm not aware a similar feature in Outlook's own e-mail editor, but that certainly doesn't mean it's not there.

Comment: How does the user set Word as the editor/composer?

Comment: @Thomas http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/turn-word-on-or-off-as-your-e-mail-editor-or-viewer-HP005242849.aspx

Comment: It turns out that for Outlook 2007, Microsoft Office Word 2007 is always enabled and cannot be disabled: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/change-the-outlook-e-mail-editor-HA010252615.aspx